# Migrating JaVers from 3.14 to 5.9.1

Tags: java, javers

I am attempting to migrate from JaVers v3.14.0 to v5.9.1 in production. I am using spring + hibernate. It seems that one of the breaking changes in 5.9.1 has to do with the schema since DDL fails.

For example:

```
aused by: org.polyjdbc.core.exception.SchemaManagerException: [DDL_ERROR] Failed to run DDL:
CREATE TABLE jv_commit (
commit_pk BIGINT NOT NULL,
author VARCHAR(200),
commit_date TIMESTAMP,
commit_id NUMERIC(22,2),
CONSTRAINT jv_commit_pk PRIMARY KEY(commit_pk)
) 
...
Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: relation "jv_commit" already exists
```

There is nothing that google find on JaVers +Migration and nothing I can find in release notes or documentation. Has anybody attempted this?

Answer (score 1):

When upgrading to the newer version, Javers runs DB migration scripts automatically. So there are no migration guides, it should work out of the box. Maybe the bug you are experiencing isn't caused by the migration. It has to be debugged. Try to set breakpoint here https://github.com/javers/javers/blob/1e2d87e649ea5342d55996e3f0f83555e952a9f2/javers-persistence-sql/src/main/java/org/javers/repository/sql/schema/JaversSchemaManager.java#L224 and check why Javers fails to realize that the table `jv_commit` exists (and then tries to create it).

Comment: https://github.com/javers/javers/blob/1e2d87e649ea5342d55996e3f0f83555e952a9f2/javers-persistence-sql/src/main/java/org/javers/repository/sql/schema/JaversSchemaManager.java#L257

This `do {} while()` block runs out of `resultSet.next()` - my suspicion is `&& !tableSchemaName.equalsIgnoreCase("public")`. In my case several apps run on same database and are separated by schemas so in this case `jv_commit` is in schema named (let's say) `product`. So my first assumption is that if it would've been `public` it would've reached `return true;`